# How to add some text for a layer deckgl?

Tags: deck.gl

I am new with deckgl. I want to add some text to my layer (any type of layer) but I'm not able to

Here is my example:

```js
const layer = new PointCloudLayer({
  id: 'point-c-layer',
  data: [{
    position: [39.826168, 21.422510],
    normal: [-1, 0, 0],
    color: [204, 102, 0],
  }],
  radiusPixels: 20,    
});
```

What I should add in data array to add my text to this layer?

Answer (score 1):

Add the text to a separate [TextLayer](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/tree/master/examples/text-layer/text-layer) like this:

```js
const text = new TextLayer({
  id: 'text-layer',
  data: [
    {text: '#San Francisco', coordinates: [-122.425586, 37.775049]}
  ]
})

return (<DeckGL {...viewport} layers={[pointcloud, text]} />)
```